# Error 1004 function and selecting multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble specific cells based on a certain value.

The idea is if a cell in "B" contains 119, then the columns "B:E" ,"G:H","J:M" are selected and copied to a different section of the same worksheet. I don't want the rows command to select the whole row as there are cells with formulas i do not want to be moved.

Additionally the error being displayed is 1004: object definition error and i am struggling to see what part is throwing the function.

Any help would be greatly appriciated

````
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long, y As Range

endRow = 31 ' last row
pasteRowIndex = 67 ' paste row
Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("B:E,G:H,J:M")

For r = 1 To endRow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

    If Cells(r, Columns("B").Column).Value = "119" Then 'Found

            'Copy the current row
            Rows(r, y).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Switch to the row where i want to paste it & paste

            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Next match
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1



    End If
Next r
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps like this, though not sure whether you are pasting into A67 downwards?

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long, y As Range

endRow = 31 ' last row
pasteRowIndex = 67 ' paste row

Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("B:E,G:H,J:M")

For r = 1 To endRow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria
    If Cells(r, "B").Value = 119 Then 'Found
        'Copy the current row
        Intersect(y, Rows(r)).Copy Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1) 'not sure about this destination
        pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, i will try this one, basically i had been given a template that needed some rows to be sorted based on the value in column "B", the kicker was they can't be normally sorted and needed to be in specific areas of the same sheet.